# MySQL Explain. How to improve type ref extra NULL

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I'm struggling to find the right index to the query shown below (I have improved it from minutes to 20 seconds but it needs to be faster):

```
explain extended SELECT cta.NRO_CUENTA
,  (IF(aut.Reversada=1,-1,1)*IFNULL(ctamov.Importe,0.0))  AS ImporteTotalConsumos
,  (IF(aut.Reversada=1,-1,1)*IFNULL(ctamov.ImporteCuotas,0.0)) AS ImporteTotalCuotas
,  (IF(aut.Reversada=1,-1,1)*IFNULL(ctamov.ImporteAdelantos,0.0)) AS ImporteTotalAdelantos
,  (IF(aut.Reversada=1,-1,1)*IFNULL(ctamov.ImportePrestamos,0.0)) AS ImporteTotalPrestamos
, aut.Reversada
, date_format(cta.FEC_RENEWAL,'%Y%m%d') 
FROM recomponer_cuenta_limit rcpCta
INNER JOIN cuentas cta   ON rcpCta.NRO_CUENTA = cta.NRO_CUENTA
INNER   JOIN cuentas_movimientos ctamov ON cta.NRO_CUENTA = ctamov.Cuenta
INNER JOIN autorizaciones aut ON aut.uKey = ctamov.uKey;
```

I need all rows from `rcpCta` (1K to 50K rows depending on run, just one column which is PK, if is filled in batch process), `cta`: 1M rows, `ctamov`: 25M rows, and `aut`: 90M rows.

```
+------+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| # id |  select_type |  table  |   type  |                     possible_keys                    |             key             |  key_len |           ref          |  rows |  filtered |                Extra                |
+------+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|    1 |  SIMPLE      |  rcpCta |  index  |  PRIMARY                                             |  PRIMARY                    |        4 |                        |  1000 |  100.00   |  Using index                        |
|    1 |  SIMPLE      |  cta    |  eq_ref |  PRIMARY                                             |  PRIMARY                    |        4 |  SRT.rcpCta.nro_cuenta |     1 |  100.00   |  null                               |
|    1 |  SIMPLE      |  ctamov |  ref    |  cuentas_movimientos_cuenta,cuentas_movimientos_uKey |  cuentas_movimientos_cuenta |        4 |  SRT.rcpCta.nro_cuenta |     7 |  100.00   |  Using index condition; Using where |
|    1 |  SIMPLE      |  aut    |  ref    |  autorizaciones_uKey                                 |  autorizaciones_uKey        |      387 |  SRT.ctamov.uKey       |     1 |  100.00   |  null                               |
+------+--------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+------------------------+-------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

#### Indexes

```
aut:
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX autorizaciones_autorizacion (Comercio, Terminal, Tarjeta, CodigoAutorizacion, FechaPOS, HoraPOS),
    INDEX autorizaciones_notificadas (Notificada, MomentoTransaccion),
    INDEX autorizaciones_momento (MomentoTransaccion, Tarjeta, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX autorizaciones_uKey (uKey),
    INDEX autorizaciones_momentoreversada (MomentoReversacion, uKey),
    INDEX autorizaciones_tarjeta (Tarjeta, MomentoTransaccion, Reversada, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX autorizaciones_webentidades (Sistema, MomentoSyncWebEntidades, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX autorizaciones_cuenta (Cuenta, MomentoTransaccion, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX autorizaciones_conciliacion (FECHA_CONCILIACION, id)
ctamov:
    INDEX cuentas_movimientos_cuenta (Cuenta, Momento, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX cuentas_movimientos_uKey (uKey, Momento, TipoTransaccion),
    INDEX cuentas_movimientos_momento (Momento, uKey, TipoTransaccion)
cta:
    PRIMARY KEY (NRO_CUENTA),
    INDEX cuentas_ultima_transaccion (MomentoUltimaTransaccion, NRO_CUENTA),
    INDEX cuentas_creacion (MomentoCreacion, NRO_CUENTA),
    INDEX cuentas_ultima_actualizacion (MomentoUltimaActualizacion, NRO_CUENTA),
    INDEX cuentas_ultima_nominacion (Entidad, MomentoUltimaNovedadNominacion, MomentoSyncSPCNominacion)
rcpCta: 
      PRIMARY KEY (NRO_CUENTA)
```

Comment: 1) Where are indices for `recomponer_cuenta_limit AS rcpCta` table? 2) Look for `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON cuentas_movimientos (uKey, Cuenta)`. And, just in case, in reverse order.

Comment: @Akina sorry, just added, it is one column table and PK. It is populated in a batch process, rows might vary from 1K to 50K. Will test what you suggested.